# Golang Passing Function Arguments with Arbitrary Interfaces

Tags: function, reflection, go, function-pointers

The following code works nicely:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func WrapperFunc(fn func(int,int) int) int{
    return fn(3,4)
}

func add(a,b int) int{
    return a + b
}

func main(){
    fmt.Println(WrapperFunc(add))
}
```

I want to pass additional parameters that implements a specific interface.  For instance, I modify the code as follows:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type RequestBody interface {
    GetDescription() string
}

type LoginRequest struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

func (lr LoginRequest) GetDescription() string{
    return "cool function"
}

func WrapperFunc(fn func(int, int, RequestBody) int) int {
    lr := LoginRequest{}
    return fn(3, 4, lr)
}

func add(a, b int, lr LoginRequest) int {
    fmt.Println(lr.GetDescription())
    return a + b
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(WrapperFunc(add))
}
```

It fails with the error below:

```
cannot use add (type func(int, int, LoginRequest) int) as type func(int, int, RequestBody) int in argument to WrapperFunc
```

However, when I do not implement the `GetDescription` as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type RequestBody interface {
    GetDescription() string
}

type LoginRequest struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

func WrapperFunc(fn func(int, int, RequestBody) int) int {
    lr := LoginRequest{}
    return fn(3, 4, lr)
}

func add(a, b int, lr LoginRequest) int {
    return a + b
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(WrapperFunc(add))
}
```

It fails with second error, as interface is not implemented (as expected).

```
cannot use lr (type LoginRequest) as type RequestBody in argument to fn:
    LoginRequest does not implement RequestBody (missing GetDescription method)
 cannot use add (type func(int, int, LoginRequest) int) as type func(int, int, RequestBody) int in argument to WrapperFunc
```

So, it understands that, in `WrapperFunc` body, I can only call `fn` with `int`, `int` and an `RequestBody interface` that implements the `GetDescription`, yet I still cannot pass it in the function phase. How can I accomplish this? I want to wrap functions that can have parameters that their type can change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `WrapperFunc()` expects a value of function type:

```
func(int, int, RequestBody) int
```

And you try to pass `add` to it which has a function type:

```
func(int, int, LoginRequest) int
```

2 [function types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) are equal if both have the same parameter and result types. This does not hold in the above mentioned 2 function types: `RequestBody` and `LoginRequest` are different types, and so function types having these as (or among) parameters are different types.

You may only pass `add` to `WrapperFunc()` if you change its parameters to match the required type:

```
func add(a, b int, lr RequestBody) int {
    fmt.Println(lr.GetDescription())
    return a + b
}
```

Now `add()` has the same function type as `fn` in the parameters of `WrapperFunc()`, so your code will compile and run.

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XJfbESwsz4)</kbd>)

```
cool function
7
```

**Notes:**

Now `lr` parameter in `add()` is of type `RequestBody` and not `LoginRequest`. You may use it like a `RequestBody`, which is you may call its `GetDescription()` method. In `WrapperFunc()` you don't have to change anything, as `LoginRequest` implements `RequestBody`, so it is allowed to call `fn()` with a value of `LoginRequest`, and an interface value of type `RequestBody` will automatically, implicitly be created and passed to `fn` (which is `add()` in your case).

Note that in `add()` since parameter is now a `RequestBody`, you can't refer to fields of `LoginRequest`. You may if the value implementing the interface is indeed a value of type `LoginRequest`, in which case you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the wrapped `LoginRequest` value should you need it.